# Adding new row does not create new span with new character counter message

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sharepoint-2013

There is character count to be displayed for every description field. After every new row, the new description field should have its own character counter. However, how to set different SpanIDs and display in respective SpanIds

```
<div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right: 7px;padding-left: 26px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
                                 <span style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Description</span>
                                 <div class = "row" style="padding-bottom:10px;"> </div>
                                 <div style="display: inline-flex;width: 150%;">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control controlheight claimdesc" onkeyup="ReasonCodeDescCounter(this.id)" id="txt_complaint_breakdowndesc" maxlength="85">
                                    <span style="padding-left: 5%;line-height: 25px;" class="mandatoryinput"></span>            
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="validationError">
                                    <span id="breakdowndescvalid" class="important">Mandatory</span>
                                    <span id="reasoncodecharactersLeft" class="important"></span>
                                 </div>
```

```
$(".newadd").append("<div class=\"additionalrow\" id=\"additionalrow"+txti+"\"><div class='col-sm-5 col-xs-5' style='margin-top:10px;'><div style=\"padding-left: 5%;display: inline-flex;width: 150%;\"><input type='text' class='form-control controlheight claimdesc' maxlength='85' id='txt_complaint_breakdowndesc" + txti + "' onkeyup='javascript:return ReasonCodeDescCounter(this.id)'><span style=\"padding-left: 3%;line-height: 25px;\" class=\"mandatoryinput\"></span></div><div class=\"validationError\"><span id=\"breakdowndesc"+ txti +"valid\" class=\"important\">Mandatory</span><span style=\"display: block;\" id='reasoncodecharactersLeft"+ txti + "' class=\"important\" ></span></div></div>
```

````
function ReasonCodeDescCounter(id){
    var x = document.getElementById(id).value;
    var lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft;
    lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft=0;

    var lengthCount = x.length;              
    var lengthdata = x;     
    var reasoncodecharactersLeft;
    if (lengthCount > 85) {
        id.value = id.value.substring(0, lengthdata-1);
        reasoncodecharactersLeft = lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft;                   
    }
    else {                   
        reasoncodecharactersLeft = 85 - lengthCount;   
        lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft=   reasoncodecharactersLeft;
    }
    
    $("#reasoncodecharactersLeft").css('display', 'block');
    $("#reasoncodecharactersLeft").text(reasoncodecharactersLeft + ' Characters left');          
}
```[Missing Span after new description field in new row][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ9S6.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `this` inside your function where `this` refer to input box where keyup event has occur then using that you can get value of input and then show required messages in spans .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var txti = 2;
//added left class
$(".newadd").append("<div class=\"additionalrow\" id=\"additionalrow" + txti + "\"><div class='col-sm-5 col-xs-5' style='margin-top:10px;'><div style=\"padding-left: 5%;display: inline-flex;width: 150%;\"><input type='text' class='form-control controlheight claimdesc' maxlength='85' id='txt_complaint_breakdowndesc" + txti + "' onkeyup='javascript:return ReasonCodeDescCounter(this)'><span style=\"padding-left: 3%;line-height: 25px;\" class=\"mandatoryinput\"></span></div><div class=\"validationError\"><span id=\"breakdowndesc" + txti + "valid\" class=\"important\">Mandatory</span><span style=\"display: block;\" id='reasoncodecharactersLeft" + txti + "' class=\"important left\" ></span></div></div>")


function ReasonCodeDescCounter(el) {
  var x = $(el).val() //value of input
  var lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft;
  lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft = 0;

  var lengthCount = x.length;
  var lengthdata = x;
  var reasoncodecharactersLeft;
  if (lengthCount > 85) {
    $(el).val(x.substring(0, lengthdata - 1));
    reasoncodecharactersLeft = lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft;
  } else {
    reasoncodecharactersLeft = 85 - lengthCount;
    lastreasoncodedesccharactersLeft = reasoncodecharactersLeft;
  }
  //get span tag
  $(el).closest(".col-sm-5").find(".left").css('display', 'block');
  $(el).closest(".col-sm-5").find(".left").text(reasoncodecharactersLeft + ' Characters left');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right: 7px;padding-left: 26px;padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <span style="padding-bottom: 20px;">Description</span>
    <div class="row" style="padding-bottom:10px;"> </div>
    <div style="display: inline-flex;width: 150%;">
      <!--pass `this` as well-->
      <input type="text" class="form-control controlheight claimdesc" onkeyup="ReasonCodeDescCounter(this)" id="txt_complaint_breakdowndesc" maxlength="85">
      <span style="padding-left: 5%;line-height: 25px;" class="mandatoryinput"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="validationError">
      <span id="breakdowndescvalid" class="important">Mandatory</span>
      <!--added left classs-->
      <span id="reasoncodecharactersLeft" class="important left"></span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="newadd"></div>
```

Comment: The span is not getting displayed and hence the character count is not seen. Otherwise the calcuation is happening correctly

Comment: see inside element tab of browser if span is present or not .

Comment: Thank you..The above code sent is working fine. I had missed adding class left